# Amazon Mobile Analytics data not showing up in web console

Tags: cordova, amazon-web-services, amazon-mobile-analytics

I'm using the AWS Mobile Analytics JavaScript SDK through a Cordova/PhoneGap app. My whitelist is set to allow all traffic. While looking through my network trace I can see the events being sent properly over HTTP:

```
HTTP 202 _session.start
HTTP 202 custom events
...
HTTP 202 _session.stop
```

Heres an exmple of the `x-amz-Client-Context` header that im sending:

```
{
"client": {
    "client_id":"xxx",
    "app_title":"HelloWorld",
    "app_version_name":"0.0.1",
    "app_version_code":"0.0.1",
    "app_package_name":"com.company.hello"
},
"env":{
    "platform":"unknown",
    "platform_version":"46.0.2490.76",
    "model":"Chrome",
    "make":"unknown",
    "locale":"en-US"
},
"services":{
    "mobile_analytics":{
        "app_id":"xxx",
        "sdk_name":"aws-sdk-mobile-analytics-js",
        "sdk_version":"0.9.1:2.3.3"
    }
},
"custom":{}
```

}

My question is why isn't the data showing up in the management console? I understand that it could take up to 60 min., but I've been testing over a couple days and haven't seen any results show up in graphs.

Comment: Do you have any error logs that you can share?

Comment: No runtime or network errors. Everything runs fines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are receiving 202 responses from the Mobile Analytics end-point that indicates that the requests to aggregate your data were received by the Mobile Analytics service and that the format of the requests passes the general validation (as indicated here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobileanalytics/latest/ug/PutEvents.html).

However, there is a possibility that the platform you are sending may not be one of the supported platforms for aggregation in the Console. From the docs link above:

> Valid values: iphoneos, android, windowsphone, blackberry, macos, windows, linux

If you submit events for a platform that is not included in the list above those events will still be accepted and you can get them exported to S3 or RedShift but those events won't be aggregated on in the Console.

Can you please update the question with an example of an event you are sending (*please redact any sensitive information before posting the event in the question*).

Comment: This was the issue. I was sending and 'unknown' as the platform value.

Comment: Great! I'm glad you got it fixed